# Bootstrap Select dropup does not align with search results

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to fix an alignment issue with bootstrap select live search (selectpicker). The dropup menu has incorrect alignment while showing search results. The alignment fixes by itself after I scroll the page. This issue does not arise for the dropdown.

I am using bootstrap 1.14 beta 3 on bootstrap 5 for .Net 6 MVC.

Here are some pictures for reference:

1. [Bootstrap Select dropdown list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCNFa.png)
2. [Dropup alignment issues while searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQF0O.png)
3. [Dropup fixes its alignment after page scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrMLt.png)

I have only used the standard starter code from bootstrap-select official docs with some custom styling.

**Select tag**

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control form-control-md"
        data-live-search = "true"
        asp-items = Model.CountryList>
</select>
```

**Custom CSS**

```
div.dropdown-menu.open {
   max-height: 250px !important;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   height: auto
}

div.dropdown-menu.inner {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

boostrap selectpicker does not support bootstrap 5 just yet
I faced the same problem where the drop-down was misaligned  and I discovered that the previous programmers working on the project added this to the main CSS for different effects

```
.dropdown-menu {
margin-left: 3% !important;
width: 320px;
}
```

I added more CSS on the page where I needed the select picker

```
.dropdown-menu {
    margin-left:0px;
}
```